# .Net Regex split with optional items and greediness

Tags: .net, regex, parsing, split, regex-greedy

Here is a test sample of data I'm trying to parse:

```
Content1
***
Content2
***
Content3
Content3
***

Content4
***
Content5

***
***
Content6
***
***
***
Content7
```

In short, data entries separated by a separator string on a new line. I want to get Content1, Content2, Content3\r\nContent3, \r\nContent4, Content5\r\n, Content6, Content7. I tried a very simple regex `(\r\n)?^\*\*\*$(\r\n)?`, which in RegexBuddy's Split with '^$ match at line breaks' option and .Net flavour selected gives me the correct output, albeit with empty strings between multiple separators, which I understand I have to remove manually. However, the following C# code:

```
string regexPattern = string.Format(@"(\r\n)?^{0}$(\r\n)?", Regex.Escape("***"));
var records = Regex.Split(document, regexPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

returns me the whole input string. Where am I wrong here?

Also, I don't understand why the regex `(\r\n)?\*\*\*(\r\n)?`(which doesn't really suit me, because an entry can include the separator string) returns me Content1, \r\n, \r\n, Content2, \r\n, etc. Shouldn't the \r\n items be greedily grabbed? RegexBuddy gives me the correct output with this regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Where exactly does `$` match?

The main problem is that `$` matches just before `\n` character, so if there is any `\r` before `\n`, you need to specify it in the pattern. Otherwise, no match will be returned. You can test splitting the string with `"\r$"` on `"Content1\r\nContent2\r\nContent3"` to see the effect.

Just an example to show where is considered beginning of a line `^` and end of a line `$` (under `Multiline` option). First line is the original string (with new line and carriage return shown as `\n` and `\r` respectively), and the second line is annotated with the position of the zero-length string matched by `^` and `$`.

```
***\r\nConte\rn\rt3\r\nCo\nntent3
^***\r$\n^Conte\rn\rt3\r$\n^Co$\n^ntent3$
```

To resolve this problem, we just need to test for (optional) `\r` right before `$`. In the solution below in section 3, I test for optional `\r`, since `\r` may not be there if the input file comes from UNIX environment.

#### 2. Inclusion of captured text in result of `Regex.Split`:

From .NET Framework 2.0, [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ze12yx1d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will split the string at delimiter, and **also include captured text in the result array**.

To resolve the above problem, you just need to turn the *capturing groups* (capture text + grouping property) into *non-capturing groups* `(?:pattern)` (grouping property only).

#### 3. Conclusion

So the solution is:

```
var records = Regex.Split(document, @"(?:\r?\n)?^[*]{3}\r?$\n?", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/lfIIrj)

You can deal with empty strings in the result separately.